# Is it possible to execute a rawQuery on the mmssms database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am using the emulator in eclipse.
I have around 2200 text messages in the emulator
I pulled the /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db from the emulator and saw the text messages in there

SQLiteDatabase smsDB=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db", null, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Cursor people1 = smsDB.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(date) from sms", null);

I am getting the error (14) cannot open file from sqlite

I want to use the rawQuery because it seems a lot easier to write advanced SQL than the ContentProvider way.

I was able to issue simple queries using the ContentProvider but I am really hoping there is an answer to the rawQuery way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the main purpose of the ContentProvider is to keep you from directly manipulating the database, especially the system provided databases.